# Is it possible to send an arraylist as a response to jquery?

Tags: java, jquery

Is it possible to send an arraylist as a response(from action class) to jquery?If so please give sample code

Comment: You forgot to mention which server side platform you're using.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Search for JSON.

Comment: "Action class" smells much like Struts. Are you using Struts or any other Java web framework on top of JSP/Servlet? You should really explicitly mention that. Each Java web framework has really its own way to solve a generic problem. Please clarify your question and retag.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to send send an arraylist as a response(from action class) to jquery.

jQuery.getJSON() method can do this easily.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

and For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.